# How to add Device tree node for SDIO wifi card detection?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I am trying to get Azurewave AW-NB136NF be detected as a SDIO card in the linux 5.2 kernel (Yocto OS). I am using Arasan SDHCI Controller and unsure of the device tree node binding for the sdio wifi card.

Using the default Arasan SDHCI Controller node, and the SDIO wifi card is not detected. I have also tried adding "broken-cd" property into the arasan device tree but this seems to be not working as well. 
I wonder if any SDIO Function subnode is needed for the Azurewave AW-NB136NF to be detected as a SDIO wifi card. If yes, how to add this SDIO Function subnode ?

There are no device tree document specific to Azurewave AW-NB136NF card.

```
sdhci@e2800000 {
    compatible = "arasan,sdhci-5.1";
    reg = <0xe2800000 0x1000>;
    clock-names = "clk_xin", "clk_ahb";
    clocks = <&cru 8>, <&cru 18>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
    interrupts = <0 24 4>;
    phys = <&emmc_phy>;
    phy-names = "phy_arasan";
    broken-cd;
} ;
```

OUTPUT:
The card is not detected at #/sys/kernel/debug/mmcX/ios .
No dmesg for "mmcX new high speed SDIO card at address 0001"

Reference:

- [devicetree/bindings/mmc/mmc.txt](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mmc/mmc.txt)
- [devicetree/bindings/mmc/arasan,sdhci.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mmc/arasan%2Csdhci.txt)
- [Linux sdio detection](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/wi-fi/knowledge-base.entry.html/2019/01/03/linux_sdio_detection-ajSx)

Comment: You have multiple systems involved.  There is the SDHCI bus controller, the wifi driver and 802.11 infrastructure.  According to [wikipedia](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/AzureWave_Wireless_Adapters) you need a Broadcom BCM43231 driver.  The configuration of wifi involves many things. It needs a large amount of code for unmanaged as the Linux kernel needs to track wifi state; you need to build this into the kernel.  Look at [b43 Kconfig](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/b43/Kconfig?h=v5.3-rc2) and other files in that directory.

Comment: You really need to understand how power up flow works and what brings your card up and running. Besides the fact of plenty quirks usually needed for SDHCI controller implementation itself.

Comment: I have tried adding the sub-node for the wifi card based on : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/net/wireless/brcm%2Cbcm43xx-fmac.txt.
However, the card seems to be not detected as a SDIO device by the controller. Without the wifi driver, I believe the card should be detected by the controller as the SDIO device as this is handled by drivers/mmc/core/sdio.c. Is this correct ?